# Vue.js: how to use the afterEnter hook with an async component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I would like to use JS Hook as described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks). Specially, I want to use the `afterEnter` hook with an async component.

This is my async component:

```
Vue.component('example', function(resolve, reject){
    let data = {
        text: 'test data',
    };

    $.post('http://example.com', data, function(r){
        r = JSON.parse(r);

        if( r.success ) {
            resolve({
                template: r.data,
                afterEnter: function(el, done){
                    console.log('test');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is what the ajax call gets from the server, and it's what is passed to the template in `r.data`.

```
<transition v-on:after-enter="afterEnter"></transition>
```

These are the two errors that I get.

`[Vue warn]: Property or method "afterEnter" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.`

`[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "after-enter": got undefined`

Is it possible to use JS hooks with async components? And if not, how should I approach this? My objective is to run custom JS after Vue (and/or vue-router) inject the component template onto the page, so that I can initiliaze image sliders and whatnot. It is important that my custom JS fires every time the component is navigated to, and not only on the first load.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That warning means that Vue is looking for (but unable to find) a property or method named `"afterEnter"`, which you reference in your template. You have defined `afterEnter` in your `resolve` function as if it is a lifecycle hook, but it needs to be one of your Vue instance's methods.

So, your `resolve` function should look like this:

```
resolve({
  template: r.data,
  methods: {
    afterEnter: function(el, done) {
      console.log('test');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you... still learning Vue so I didn't notice my mistake.